# Kendo Autocomplete is not displaying json dataset results

Tags: proxy, web-config

I am using kendoautocomplete using json method, where my json method returns DataSet results. below is code.
$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataTextField: 'Text',
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Home/getPostcodeData",
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    pageSize: 20,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

return Json(dataSet, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use combobox instead of autocomplete since you have dataValueField?

Here is my code example and everything works fine.

HTML

```
<input id="combobox" name="combobox" type="text"/>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
                placeholder: "Select Value",
                dataValueField: 'Id',
                dataTextField: 'Text',
                filter: "startswith",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "@Url.Action("Test","Home")",
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json'
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        });
```

C#

```
public JsonResult Test()
        {
            var test = new List<TestModel>
            {
                new TestModel(){ Id = 1, Text = "Text 1" },
                new TestModel(){ Id = 2, Text = "Text 2" },
                new TestModel(){ Id = 3, Text = "Text 3" },
                new TestModel(){ Id = 4, Text = "Text 4" },
                new TestModel(){ Id = 5, Text = "Text 5" },
            };

            return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```